# what is the impact of obsolete baseline in UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

when baselines are obsolete will it have any ill-effect?

For example if the baseline was already rebased by many, if i obsolete the baseline what will happen?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add some IBM technotes and bug references.

Answer (score 1):

You can, **but shouldn't** obsolete a baseline which is currently used as a foundation baseline on an existing stream.
Even if it is possible, it used to have some side-effects like:

- stopping other baselines from being seen by the "`lsbl`" command ([swg1IC42113](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC42113), fixed in ClearCase 7.0.x).
- not showing the Baselines when foundation baseline is locked or obsolete ([ss](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC41514), fixed in ClearCase 7.0.x).

(older ClearCase like 2003 could have an issue if an ancestor of a baseline being rebased was obsolete: [swg21214304](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21214304). But that has been fixed long time ago)

---

It (ie, "obsoleting a foundation baseline") still has a current (May 2012, ClearCase 7.1.x) open bug:
[swg1PM63804](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PM63804): 
PM63804: Lock obsolete a foundation baseline of a child stream results in all baselines on that stream not being displayed in the base.

> Abstract: If a component baseline that happens to be also a foundation baseline of a stream is locked-obsolete, then the component tree browser with the '`Show obsolete baselines`' tick-box unset, **hides not only that baseline, but also and
>   incorrectly *all* the baselines of the stream of which the just locked-obsoleted baseline is the foundation baseline**.
>
> WORKAROUND:
>
> - **In the Component tree browser window there is no known workaround**.
> - From command line, this was fixed with APAR IC42113, the '`cleartool lsbl -tree`' command correctly hides the locked-obsolete foundation baseline, and correctly lists the
>     non-locked-obsolete following baselines on that stream.

---

The other current bug is [swg1IC39164](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC39164):assertion failed for GUI rebase to latest baseline (ClearCase 7.1.x), and should be fix by upgrading to the latest patch.

---

Other than that,  there are mostly advantages to obsolete old baseline, mainly because it will un-clutter the vast number of objects displayed when doing a browse baselines.