# ClearCase: Housekeeping

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In my continued quest to learn and tame our use of ClearCase [UCM], I have realized that every label, activity, baseline, stream and [almost every view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782443/4083529) from the beginning of time is open and visible within our ClearCase setup.

In a similar vein to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117752/4083529), I am under the belief that it could be beneficial to [lock obsolete](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) our old baselines at least.

**Is there an easy way to find baselines older than a certain date** (from Windows in my case)?

I've been struggling with the `cleartool find`, `lsbl` and `desc` commands and feel I am missing something simple.

As a second part to this, **if I did find a command - should it be used?**  Is there a danger in almost blindly selecting all [old] baselines and locking them obsolete in this manner [other than those reasons already stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117752/4083529) above]?

Is there another recommended method for this, or should I be looking at housekeeping at a different level?  Different object?  Or not at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility, that I describe in "[How to get the recent baselines of a project in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979510/6309)" is to use the [`fmt_ccase` option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) combined with [`cleartool lsbl`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-9):

```
cleartool lsbl -fmt "%d %n\" -stream...
```

You still need to parse and sort the output, but that is a start.

> should it be used? Is there a danger in almost blindly selecting all [old] baselines and locking them obsolete in this manner?

Not really (beside the [bug I mentioned about foundation baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117752/6309)): it is a purge policy, and it will need to be adjusted project by project.

Answer (score 1):

Given the irremovable nature of a lot of UCM metadata, you may also want to consider migrating the components and projects to new VOBs. Locking a baseline/stream obsolete only makes it not display, it will still be looked up when a tool gets the baselines in the stream. Depending on your project architecture and baselining process, this could be anywhere from somewhat to extremely painful...

There isn't anything wrong with a project/component structure that has been around for over a decade. I work every day on one. If you're only worried about stuff being visible, the lock obsolete process is fine. if you're having other issues as well, then a "clean slate" PVOB/CVOB may resolve them.